# What files do I need to recover MySQL databases from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, backup

I have a now non-bootable install of Ubuntu.  What files do I need to copy to backup all of the MySQL databases (including database users and permissions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any dumps, you want the files in `/var/lib/mysql/<dbname>`.  Since the system won't boot, I would boot with a live cd a mount the hard drive read only.

It should be okay if the DB was not running when when it shut down.  If it was running, there might be some corruption.  There might also be some file system corruption since it won't boot. [Here is a post](http://www.felipecruz.com/repair-mysql-database.php) on recovering databases when they are in a unclean state.

In the future, the proper way to backup databases (if you don't use special software for it) is to create a dump of the database, and then back up those dumps.

Comment: The link is broken for "Here is a post "

Answer (score 0):

The database dumps.

You *might* be able to copy the data directory to another machine and stand up mysql there.  But you will have better luck with actual dumps.

man mysqldump.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I can't boot the OS that MySQL is on. I'm guessing that mysqldump wouldn't be able to help me without a running server.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned the data directory that Kyle expanded on.