# Re-configuring mysql-server 5.1

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, update

Some days ago I had some problems with updates, and this ended up with a problem that I already solved in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/235683/restart-mysql-keeping-the-data) . The problem is that now I want to update again, but it seems that I cannot do it automatically, because when I use the update manager it gets stuck while configuring mysql-server 5.1, in the line :

Configuring mysql-server 5.1 (5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10)...

I have been looking for some solution but it seems hard because actually I don't know where to start, so any hints are appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Alf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run mysql-server-5.1 config script from console:

```
# sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.config
# echo $?
0
```

If the problem persists, then add line in /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.config

```
#!/bin/bash -e

set -x

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
```

And run /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.config. Output add to question.